# Using multiple QSyntaxHighlighter in one QPlainTextEdit

Tags: qt, syntax-highlighting

I have written two syntax highlighter: one for CSS and one for HTML.
They work well.

But, I want to color CSS code in HTML code (inside <style> tag), so I want to be able to use multiple QSyntaxHighlighter in one QPlainTextEdit.

Is there a way to do what I want?
I cannot instantiate two QSyntaxHighlighter objects on the same QPlainTextEdit because only the second object will be used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to handle switching between the different highlighting modes yourself, within a single syntax highlighter.

I'd start with your HTML highlighter, since it should be able to tell when you're inside a `<style>` tag. Use the [`setCurrentBlockState`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsyntaxhighlighter.html#setCurrentBlockState) to mark that block as CSS, and delegate to the CSS renderer.

The basic idea is illustrated in the [`QSyntaxHighlighter`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) docs (switching between comment/code modes) and the example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, with one Syntax Highlighter, this is possible. But, is there a way to do what I want with separate highlighters? With one syntax highlighter, there will be lots of duplicated code (one syntax highlighter for HTML, CSS and JS, one for CSS and one for JS) and some syntax highlighters will be very big.

Comment: No, not on a single document. But you can arrange your code so that it doesn't duplicate too much if you're careful. Only put the code to detect where/when you're changing languages in the highlighter itself. Put the actual language logic in separate classes and use these helper classes from the highlighter.